# How to you detect when a virtual machine has resumed

Tags: windows, sockets, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have an application that is trying to use utulize virtual machines that are kept in a suspended mode. To clarify with suspended I mean the virtual machine will launched and brought into a state where it's fully booted and then suspended, so on demand the machine could be brought live withing a few seconds (as opposed to a full boot cycle of several minutes).

Now as soon as my virtual machine comes online I would like it to interface with a message queue. However I've come across a difficulty, if I suspend the virtual machine when the virtual machine has open tcp/ip connections e.g. to the message queue, the socket isn't discovered as invalid until a good 30-60 seconds later. So I was wondering if there is a good a way to handle these type of problems, by detecting if the virtual machine was resumed from suspension.

A workaround I've had some promising results by configuring the virtual machine without any network interface enabled, and keep waiting for a network interface to be connected before establishing the initial connection. However I would still like to know are there alternatives to my scenario that might be better, or something that could be tried as a backup plan.

Comment: As a very simple workaround, you could watch the time of day every second. When it changes for more than 1 second you just returned from suspension.

Comment: In one C# project, we used NetworkAvailabilityChanged (many examples available, e.g. http://code-programmming.blogspot.be/2013/03/handle-networkavailabilitychanged-event.html) reaction time around 5 - 10 seconds.

Comment: You could try setting the tcp keep alive option. Some more info here for Linux: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/

Comment: Keep-alive wouldn't do any good at all in this case, it's just a technique to prevent the connection from closing. But you're overlooking the big picture, the connection already *has* been closed forcible, that happens while the machine is suspended. Without a receiving end-point for the keep alive mechanism for maybe multiple consecutive days; the connection would end up closed.